# Deep Reinforcement Learning (keras-rl) Early stopping

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, keras-rl

According to these guys (https://nihit.github.io/resources/spaceinvaders.pdf) it is possible to perform Early Stopping with Deep Reinforcement Learning. I used that before with Deep Learning on Keras, but, how to do that on keras-rl? in the same fit() function or before sending the model to the agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you could just use keras's callback; if you really want it in the package, grab it from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py) and put it in [here](https://github.com/keras-rl/keras-rl/blob/master/rl/callbacks.py). Otherwise, I would try:

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

early_stop = EarlyStopping(patience=69) # epochs stagnation before termination

# from their example cem_cartpole.py
cem.fit(env, nb_steps=100000, visualize=False, callbacks=[early_stop], verbose=2)
```

Comment: I get the message: `WARNING:tensorflow:Early stopping conditioned on metric "mae" which is not available. Available metrics are: episode_reward,nb_episode_steps,nb_steps`. How to define the metric to be used?